# SharePoint Hosted-App Using DateTimeControl Get null Reference

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Hi i have created a `<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="ToDateTime" ClientIDMode="Static" LocaleId="2057" AutoPostBack="false" DatePickerFrameUrl="../_layouts/15/iframe.aspx" runat="server" />`

in my App.Js file i have written this

```
var listItemCustom = document.getElementById("FromDateTimeDate");
```

I get error on this line because it cant find by ID why?

Answer (score 0):

This control generates a input tag with new id attribute when page is rendered. For example,Control ID is "Expires" and then sharepoint generates a input tag with 'id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Expires_ExpiresDate"'. You can check this by IE Developer Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from **SharePoint Datetimecontrol** use:

```
var listItemCustom = document.getElementById("FromDateTimeDateDate");
alert(listItemCustom.value);
```

just add **Date** at the end you will get the object.